# How to deploy monorepo powered by turborepo to Vercel?

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, vercel, monorepo

Recently, Turborepo is acquired by Vercel. So I was excited to experiment with that. I created a turbo repo project by running

```
pnpx create-turbo
```

Then I tried to deploy it to Vercel following the documentation [here](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/git/monorepos).

It is failing with error "could not found tsconfig/nextjs.json"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error was actually caused at tsconfig.json file inside the web module.

The structure of the repo is as follows

```
- apps
  - docs
  - web
- packages
  - config
  - tsconfig
  - ui
```

The content of `apps/web/tsconfig.json` is

```
{
  "extends": "tsconfig/nextjs.json",
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Ideally, it should have been able to work as turbo should understand that.

I could finally deploy the `web` project with following settings on Vercel

```
ROOT DIRECTORY: /app/web
BUILD COMMAND: cd ../.. && yarn build
INSTALL COMMAND: cd ../.. && yarn install
```

Update: (Answer from comments and updated docs)

- you need to override the Install Command with npm install --prefix=../.. [(step 3.5)](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/git/monorepos#step-3.5:-optional-settings-if-using-npm-workspaces).

Comment: Was having the same error. Afte re-reading the docs, I realized you need to override the Install Command with `npm install --prefix=../..` ([step 3.5](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/git/monorepos#step-3.5:-optional-settings-if-using-npm-workspaces)).

Comment: @Camilo Yup, that solved my problem as well!

Answer (score 0):

Please upvote Camilo's comment under mayank1513's post as the source (I'm just reposted for visibility and I didn't see it at first and wasted several hours)

**If you're using NPM on Vercel with Turborepo** please follow [this step from Vercel](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/git/monorepos#step-3.5:-optional-settings-if-using-npm-workspaces). If you don't you'll get build errors saying roughly "can't find package".

Hope this helps!